# Another question about a proof that a group is abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

G is a group, $A,B\le G$ :
$$x^{-1}Ax\in A$$ $$x^{-1}Bx\in B$$

And I already proved that AB is a sub-group and $x^{-1}ABx\in AB$

Now I need to prove that $$ab = ba$$ for any $a\in A, b\in B$ and I have additional information that: $$A\bigcap B\:=\left\{e\right\}$$ which implies that |AB| = |A|*|B|.

Oh, and I have a clue: to look at $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ which I supose is $e$, but dont see how to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have $ba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A$, since $\forall x \in G, xAx^{-1} \subset A$ ?
Hence $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A$. You just need to do the same with $B$, and you would have $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A \cap B = \{e\}$, so $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=e$

Comment: nope, I'd write it correctly. But your idea is correct and it can be implied in this case eather. Because: $aba^{-1}/ in B$ * $b^{-1}$ still in B. But from other view: $bab^{-1}/in A$ and the same conclusion, he's in A. So he is in the intersection wich is e.